# How to pass php array values to Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

How to pass a php array values dynamically to jquery array to draw a graph ?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var line = new RGraph.Line('cvs', [])
  // how to pass php array values to this jquery space dynamically
  .set('labels', ['9:30','10:00','10:30','11:00','11:30','12:00'])
  .draw()
})
```

Comment: This is what AJAX is for. There are tons of resources on how to use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on when you need the information.

If just need to generate the information on page load, then you can simply echo the variables through PHP within the Javascript, which will be dynamically loaded into the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var line = new Rgraph.Line('cvs', [])
        .set('labels', [<?php
            $index = 0;
            $length = count($elements); 
            foreach($elements as $element) {
                echo "'" . $element . "'";
                if ($index != $length - 1) {
                    echo ",";
                }
            }
        ?>])
        .draw()
});
```

If you want this content to be generated AFTER page load, you will have to use a technology called AJAX (Asynchrounous Javascript and XML), except instead of XML, you'll most likely be using JSON (Javascript Object Notation).

Check out the [jQuery AJAX Documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)